# how to use cast in c++

Tags: c++

I have a question related to the static_cast in c++.

I have :

- a class B and its derived class D
- a class BData and its derived class DData

Here is the code:

```
class B 
{
  public:
    B(BData * pb)
    {
    }
};

class D : public B 
{
  public:
    D(DData * pd) : B( static_cast<BData*>(pd))
    {
    }
};
```

The compilation always gives an error:

```
error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'DData *' to 'BData *',
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Are you sure your `DD -> BD` inheritence is visible? Did you inherit publicly?

Comment: If DD is derived from DD, you wouldn't need the cast. Also, the error message says something about `DData` and `BData`. What are those?

Comment: The error message is quite clear

Comment: Can you maybe use `Foo` and `Bar` and their derivations as variable names and post real code.

Comment: The error message tells you that the problem involves `DData` and `BData`; you should show their definitions if you want answers that aren't guesses.

Answer (score 2):

> **I can't use `static_cast` in the constructor?**

You can use `static_cast` in a constructor.

The error message tells you exactly why you get an error,
You are trying to cast unrelated classes(`DData` and `BData`). You cannot do that with `static_cast`.

On a side note, Your code example and error message do not match, post your real code.
If your real code is as you described then it should just **[work fine](http://ideone.com/V511y)**.

Comment: Actually, the question says "a class BD and its derived class DD".

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: That is not the case as is clearly seen in the error message.The error message and the code posted are not even in sync.

Comment: @Als DData and BData are related. DData inherits from BData.

Comment: @qiuzmjq: Have you checked the link to Ideone in my answer?